# vim: save a list of open files and later open all files

Tags: vim

I want to save a list of open files (:ls), quit gvim, start gvim, reopen all previously opened files. I don't want to use :mksession because it doesn't work correctly (probably due to some of the plugins I'm using)

Comment: I love vim. I've been using it for over 20 years, and there are still so many commands that make it even easier and more powerful. This question has introduced me to two more. Thank you.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Maybe the bug/conflict with :mksession is only if you have parts of :mksession enabled that you don't care about.

Try this:

```
:set sessionoptions=buffers
:mksession
```

Comment: Just a small note for those who come after and have the same question I did: you can load a session in an existing vim window with the command `:so Session.vim`, or from the commandline with `vim -S Session.vim`

Comment: What about a plugin that does this always and automatically, so that if the shell that you're using vim in crashes, you always get your files back?

Answer (score 8):

Another answer suggests session manager plugins, which are great.  But I have a very lightweight alternative that I'll leave here for posterity.  (Since it has been quite a while since this question was active.)

The code below automatically saves the current session on shutdown, and sets a key command to reload it manually (handy for when I really do want a new session with new files). If you *really do* want to unconditionally restore the previous session whenever vim is started up again, uncomment the 'VimEnter' line.

As a bonus, this also enables manually saving and restoring a separate session at will with a keypress.

### Somewhere in ~/.vim/vimrc

```
" Automatically save the current session whenever vim is closed
autocmd VimLeave * mksession! ~/.vim/shutdown_session.vim

" <F7> restores that 'shutdown session'
noremap <F7> :source ~/.vim/shutdown_session.vim<CR>

" If you really want to, this next line should restore the shutdown session 
" automatically, whenever you start vim.  (Commented out for now, in case 
" somebody just copy/pastes this whole block)
" 
" autocmd VimEnter source ~/.vim/shutdown_session.vim<CR>

" manually save a session with <F5>
noremap <F5> :mksession! ~/.vim/manual_session.vim<cr>

" recall the manually saved session with <F6>
noremap <F6> :source ~/.vim/manual_session.vim<cr>
```

The user can define for herself what is in a session with the 'sessionoptions' option, mentioned above: `help sessionoptions`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple plugins that take vim's session management a little bit further.

[SessionMan](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2010) and [Autosess](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3883) provide some commands and auto saving features that you might like.

Another one is the following: http://jaredforsyth.com/blog/2010/apr/9/vim-crash-recovery/

Very short, probably a vimrc kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

I've found setting viminfo in your .vimrc can also save the last known buffer list.
Here's what I have.

> "Set viminfo to save info upon exit
>
> "help usr_21.txt
>
> "'5  : marks will be remembered up to 10 previous files
>
> ""50 : will save up to 100 lines for each register
>
> ":20  : up to 20 lines of command-line history will be remembered
>
> "%    : saves and restores the buffer list
>
> set viminfo='5,f1,\"50,:20,%,n~/.vim/viminfo